# MSpec Json.NET deserialization test fails in ReSharper but passes in NCrunch

Tags: c#, json.net, resharper, mspec, ncrunch

I have the following two unit tests: one using MSTest and one using Machine Specifications. As far as I can see they should behave identically. However, while the first one passes in both the NCrunch and ReSharper test runners, the second one fails in ReSharper.

```
using Machine.Specifications;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

// MSTest
[TestClass]
public class DeserializationTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Deserialized_object_is_the_same_type_as_the_original()
    {
        TestModel testModel = new TestModel() {Name = "John", Number = 42};
        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testModel, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });

        object deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });

        // This passes in both test runners
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(deserialized, typeof(TestModel));
    }
}

// MSpec
public class When_an_object_is_deserialized
{
    static TestModel testModel;
    static string serialized;
    static object deserialized;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        testModel = new TestModel() { Name = "John", Number = 42 };
        serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testModel, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });
    };

    Because of = () => deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });

    // This passes in NCrunch but fails in ReSharper.
    It should_be_the_same_type_as_the_original = () => Assert.IsInstanceOfType(deserialized, typeof(TestModel));
}
```

The failure message is: `Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:<UnitTestProject2.TestModel>. Actual type:<UnitTestProject2.TestModel>.` Oddly, the following does pass:

```
It should_be_the_same_type_as_the_original = () => Assert.IsTrue(testModel.GetType() == typeof(TestModel));
```

I am doing deserialization in this way because the actual code in question needs to be able to handle objects whose type is unknown until runtime. I assume there is something odd about the way Json.NET does this kind of deserialization, but why should the two test runners behave differently? I am using ReSharper 9.1 in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Today, we've released version 0.9.2 of the Machine.Specifications package which should solve this issue (see my answer below). Could you test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly there is an odd runtime effect going on due to some subtle difference in behaviour between NCrunch and ReSharper. The failure is definitely telling you something is wrong and you shouldn't dismiss it as a bug in either ReSharper or NCrunch.

When I step through the MSpec test in the debugger, the `deserialized` object shows the following error in the debugger:

> ```
> deserialized  Cannot fetch the value of field 'deserialized' because information about the containing class is unavailable.   object
> ```

It is hard to be certain without seeing your full solution, but I've seen this sort of thing happen when the build output directory contains more than one copy an assembly, possibly in a subdirectory. If different copies of an assembly are being referenced at different times by different components, then types from the assembly are sometimes not considered equal even if it is actually an identical copy of the assembly. The solution would be to make sure you only have one copy of every assembly in your build output, which ensures that everything is referencing the exact same file. It could be that the JSON converter is dynamically loading your type and getting the wrong assembly, or possibly loading it into a different load context that means its types are not considered equal with copies loaded in a different context.

There could be something about your build environment that is resulting in a duplicate copy of an assembly in the MSpec case. NCruch, in particular, doesn't execute post-build events by default (and usually shows a warning to that effect), so if you are copying files around in a post-build step then that could be one explanation for the different behaviour. You could check that by enabling post-build events in NCrunch and seeing if the failure occurs.

Another possible troubleshooting step is to use the Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) to log assembly binds, you should be able to work out exactly which assemblies are being loaded and in what load context.

UPDATE
I'm pretty sure this is an assembly binding issue caused by the JSON converter's use of an assembly at runtime. In the fusion log, I found this entry:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (05/06/2015 @ 02:01:38) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12_001\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

LOG: IJW explicit bind. File path:c:\users\tim\VS-Projects\StackOverflow\StackOverflow.30643046\bin\Debug\StackOverflow.30643046.dll.
LOG: IJW assembly bind returned a different path: C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\k3dpwn5u.uii\Machine Specifications Runner\assembly\dl3\6c41c492\c7eea8ec_279fd001\StackOverflow.30643046.dll. Use the file provided.
```

I also found this one:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (05/06/2015 @ 02:01:38) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12_001\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

WRN: The same assembly was loaded into multiple contexts of an application domain:
WRN: Context: Default | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: Context: Neither | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: This might lead to runtime failures.
WRN: It is recommended to inspect your application on whether this is intentional or not.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.


*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (05/06/2015 @ 02:04:41) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12_001\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

WRN: The same assembly was loaded into multiple contexts of an application domain:
WRN: Context: Default | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: Context: Neither | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: This might lead to runtime failures.
WRN: It is recommended to inspect your application on whether this is intentional or not.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.


*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (05/06/2015 @ 02:04:42) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12_001\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

WRN: The same assembly was loaded into multiple contexts of an application domain:
WRN: Context: Default | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: Context: Neither | Domain ID: 2 | Assembly Name: StackOverflow.30643046, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WRN: This might lead to runtime failures.
WRN: It is recommended to inspect your application on whether this is intentional or not.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
```

I also found that disabling the ReSharper unit test option "Shadow copy assemblies being tested" results in the test passing.

So I think we have the 'smoking gun'. You have conflicting assembly loads because of the way you're letting the JSON deserializer discover the type at runtime.

### UPDATE 2015-06-11

I noticed [this](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/278) on the MSpec mailing list, it might be relevant to your issue: [[machine.specifications] Shadow copying broken - creates very subtle bugs in tests](http://[machine.specifications]%20Replace%20Assembly.LoadFile()%20calls%20with%20LoadFrom()%20in%20DefaultRunner%20(#279))

Comment: Yes, disabling the "shadow copy" option worked for me. Any idea what was causing the difference between the MSTest and MSpec versions? Presumably something to do with the MSpec static context?

Comment: I didn't actually run the MSTest version but I expect the fusion log would answer the question. FusLogVw is a great tool for figuring out this sort of thing. I would bet that MSTest is not 'shadow-copying' the assemblies. Beware of just turning off the shadow copy option and forgetting all about it though. This is a warning that there are potential issues with letting JSON.Converter infer the types itself.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/278 Shadow copying broken - creates very subtle bugs in tests

Answer (score 3):

As @tim-long mentioned, the cause for this issue (and [MSpec #278](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/278)) is a bug within the MSpec runner. The bug is triggered by the ReSharper setting to shadow copy test assemblies (which is "on" by default).

The `TypeNameHandling.Objects` option of Json.NET leads to an assembly loading *by assembly name*, and therefore uses the shadow copied test assembly to load the `TestModel` type, which differs to the non-shadow copied version the MSpec runner used to load and run the test assembly. This leads to the "*Expected type:< UnitTestProject2.TestModel>. Actual type:< UnitTestProject2.TestModel>*" failure. See [#279](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/279) for further details why the test assembly is loaded twice if shadow copying is enabled.

I was able to reproduce this failure and checked that my fix [#279](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/279) also solves this issue.